# How to reference System.Xml in U-SQL code-behind

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to use the SqlGeometry.STMPolyFromText method in a U-SQL code-behind file, but I get an error saying:
The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

How do I add this reference in a U-SQL code-behind file?

Answer (score 2):

`System.Xml` is a system assembly so reference it using the `REFERENCE SYSTEM ASSEMBLY SYNTAX` as per [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763294.aspx).  A simple example:

```
REFERENCE SYSTEM ASSEMBLY [System.Xml];

@output = 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( VALUES ( "Assemblies registered." ) ) AS x(y);


OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.txt"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Also see here for additional information on registering assemblies:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/08/26/how-to-register-u-sql-assemblies-in-your-u-sql-catalog/